# How to add cross-field validation in Angular 2 with a complex model

Tags: forms, validation, angular

## Cross-Field Validation in Template Based Forms

***Question***:  Is it possible to create some sort of validation context that spans multiple fields but does not modify the underlying model? If not, is there a better way to do what I'm doing?

Given a model like this and **assuming that changing the model is not possible**:

`export interface IEvent {
  location?: {
    address: string;
    city: string;
    country: string;
  };
  onlineUrl?: string;
}`

What is the best way to build a template-based form that will require either all of the location object (address, city, country) to be populated OR the onlineUrl to be populated?

[Here is a working Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/KmwolKBa4fnDNGur6UEo?p=preview) where I have the custom validation working but there are some challenges:

1. In order to match the model, we need an ngModelGroup around the location fields, but onlineUrl should not be inside that ngModelGroup since it is not part of the location object. Since onlineUrl is not inside the ngModelGroup, it's difficult to come up with a cohesive validation approach. Notice in this example, that we've added a custom validator on the ngModelGroup, that seems to break some basic validation premises - for example, notice that when the fields are invalid that the red highlighting only shows up next to the location field because the custom validator is on the ngModelGroup and onlineUrl is not inside that group.
2. Typing in the onlineUrl field does not automatically trigger the re-validation since this field is not in the ngModelGroup that has the custom validator on it. In order to make this work I needed to add this binding: `(change)="locationGroup.control.controls.address.updateValueAndValidity()"` to the onlineUrl field in order to trigger the validation on a field inside the ngModelGroup.  This doesn't seem ideal.

***Restating the Question***: Is it possible to create some sort of validation context that spans multiple fields but does not modify the underlying model?

Answer (score 2):

You can place 'validateLocation' directive up in the top 'form' tag:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(myForm)" autocomplete="off" novalidate validateLocation>

  <fieldset ngModelGroup="location">
```

Then validate() method gets access to both location and onlineUrl via 'FormGroup.value' and will look like:

```
if (control && control.value && control.value.location) {
  let g = control.value;

  if (g.location.address && g.location.city && g.location.country)
    return null;

  if (g.onlineUrl)
    return null;
}
return {validateLocation: false}
```

Try [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vk4xVW09WRfkpnboC7qD). Form.valid would become true when either location or url is captured.